# Routing in Chrome: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular, angular2-routing

I have below code which is working fine in all browsers except chrome 
In chrome after click event it is redirecting but immediately I'm getting HTTP 404-Not Found Issue

No errors in console also removed all cookies and all

While Debugging I found that there may be some issue in polyfill.js file of angular but don't know exact reason and solution.

I kms.html page in which is start page 
in app component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, loginComponent, globalFrameComponent],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Login', component: loginComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/kms', name: 'Kms', component: globalFrameComponent }

])
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        this._router.navigate(['Login']);
    }
```

In Login Component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'

})
@Injectable()
export class loginComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {

    }

    loginClick(): void {
        debugger;
        this._router.navigate(['Kms']);
    }

}
```

In that GlobalFrameCompnent I have

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kms-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/landing/html/globalframe.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]

})
@Injectable()
export class globalFrameComponent {

//Code i.e properties and method required by view
}
```

Working in IE too, In Chrome only after login  I'm redirecting but immediately I'm getting IIS error page.. HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: It seems that you are using Router2 which is no longer available. Use Angular Router 3 which has a different syntax. Refer: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget `<base href="/">` in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

Issue with form tag, when I have content in "form" tag it's not working in chrome.